# Samba: Mac cannot access share?

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I have a anonymous share setup on my linux box.

I'd like to access it without passwords from my mac.

However, when I try to do that it crashes my Finder.

Here's the samba config:

```
[global]
  workgroup = HOBBIT
  dns proxy = no
  netbios name srvr1
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  security = user
  map to guest = bad user
  name resolve order bcast host

[theshare]
  comment = theshare
  path = /media/maja/Samba
  public = yes
  writable = yes
  available = yes
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
```

So I see the PC in the network, and I see the share:
[image: You can see the share]

But when I try to click on the folder, Finder crashes and I get this error:
[image: Finder error message]

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give the permission like this: `chmod -R a+rwX /media/maja/Samba`

Comment: Nope, did that, the issue is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this thread had the answer I was looking for: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=98704